# How to call a generator without creating list?

Tags: python, list, generator

OK, really hope this isn't too basic of a question but I haven't been able to find an answer on this topic.  Here goes.

I've slightly modified the product function from itertools and it produces exactly what I want.  However, I don't need the huge/complete output list, I just want to use its step output (z), do some math (not shown), and move on.

The problem is the only way I can call this generator is by putting the output into a list via the last 2 lines of code, which in my mind basically defeats the purpose of a generator.  I need this to get up to like 700 repeats, which will create millions of millions of lines that my memory obviously cannot/is not handling.

If I just write `a = product(range(2),repeat=30)` or anything other than exactly how it's shown below I get an error or no output. I realize I'm most likely just not grasping the concept of generators but I keep searching and trying different things and not getting anywhere.  If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
def reduction():

    def product(*args, **kwds):
        # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
        # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
        pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
        result = [[]]
        i=int()
        i=0
        for pool in pools:
            result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
        for prod in result:
            yield tuple(prod)
            z = list(tuple(prod))
            i = i+1            
        print i
    a=list()
    a=list(product(range(2),repeat=30))
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop over it?  You can loop over generators directly: `for x in product(...): ...`

Comment: you can think about it as follows: with a list, all its members are available to you all the time. With a generator, only the current step is available. If you do not need the benefit lists provide, you do not need to cast the generator to list. From your question it is not clear if you do or dont though so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @patrick that makes sense.  I didn't realize I could use a loop for generators!  However, it still looks like my system runs out of memory when trying to call it out with anything over 25 repeats...does that sound unusual?

Comment: It looks like you [copied your `product` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the documentation.  Note that the docs say: "except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory".  This version *does* build those results in memory, so it obviously runs out.  I would recommend against reinventing the wheel: use the `itertools.product` function, or at least look at the real implementation.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, OK, the for loop really makes sense and sounds like an ideal application...s maybe this is the question....using the product generator out of the box, let's say there's a potential output of over 20 million arrays of the scenario I'm interested....how would I be able to access the 40,000th array without having to write all 20 million arrays to a list and then index?  Sorry if this is a very obvious answer, but this might be the root of my misinterpretation.  Thank you.

Comment: You would use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to discard the first 39999 results. There's no way for the generator to skip them, so they are calculated and their values immediately discarded.  You would then just get the next value. `next(islice(long_generator(), 39999, None))`.